# Swift bridging method call bug

Tags: swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

Objective-C method

```
typedef void(^CompletionHandler)(NSError *error);
- (void)openWithCompletionHandler:(CompletionHandler)completionHandler authType:(AuthType)authType, ...;
```

I have tried to convert the object c code into swift code.

I tried :

```
test().openWithCompletionHandler({ (NSError) -> Void in
            }, AuthType.Test)
```

But this is code "Extra argument in call" compile error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift doesn't bridge Objective-C methods with variable arguments* (`...`), so the `openWithCompletionHandler(:authType:) method you've declared isn't showing up at all in Swift.

From the error message you're getting, I can tell that `test()` is returning an `AnyObject`, which Swift is happy to call any Objective-C method on. `UIDocument` has an `openWithCompletionHandler()` method that takes a single closure as its only argument, so Swift is complaining that you're giving it too many arguments for *that* method (even though it's not the one you want). Clear enough?

If possible, you'll need to refactor the Objective-C method to something that Swift can understand.

---

> *Note that this isn't entirely true - the `NSArray` `initWithObjects:` method is bridged to a Swift initializer with a variadic parameter, but Apple appears to be doing something non-public to make that work - similar to how they're able to clarify whether arguments and return values should be optional or not.